# Web App Builder View Count

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal

I've built a web application with Esri's Portal for ArcGIS for a client and it has a view count on the page before entering the application. I'm working to collect some metrics and I'm wondering if that's the total requests the application has had (zoom, resize, pan, search and zoom to a feature) or if it's just the number of times it's been opened by users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For web apps (including Story Maps) the number of views goes up by one every time the app is loaded.

Source: https://community.esri.com/thread/165670-is-the-story-map-view-count-unique-and-up-to-date